# Is it possible to have a usercontrol in WPF receive notification that a (multiple) property on a binded class has changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I have a usercontrol that uses several properties on a binded class.  I would like to update the control if any of the properties on this class change.

INotifyPropertyChanged only works if I bind to the property directly.  (this will work but I would have to bind to several properties for each instance of the control)

Below is a striped down version of the issue I am having.  The DirectProperty works as expected.  The ParentPropertyChangedCallback() is only fired when the ParentClass is assigned to the user control, not when any of the properties change.

Please tell me I doing something stupid =)

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
           "DirectProperty",
           typeof(bool),
           typeof(UserControl1),
           new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), DirectPropertyChangedCallBack));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentClassProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ParentClass",
            typeof(ParentClass),
            typeof(UserControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ParentClass), ParentPropertyChangedCallback));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool DirectProperty
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(DirectPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DirectPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public ParentClass ParentClass
    {
        get { return (ParentClass)GetValue(ParentClassProperty); }
        set{ SetValue(ParentClassProperty, value); }
    }
    // private void parentProperty_Changed(object)
    private static void DirectPropertyChangedCallBack(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var sourceObject = dependencyObject as UserControl1;
        if (sourceObject == null) return;

        //set rectangle 1 base on Direct Property
        sourceObject.Rectangle1.Fill =
            sourceObject.ParentClass.DirectProperty
                ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
                 : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    private static void ParentPropertyChangedCallback(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var sourceObject = dependencyObject as UserControl1;
        if (sourceObject == null) return;

        //set rectangle 2 base on ParentClass Property
        sourceObject.Rectangle2.Fill =
            sourceObject.ParentClass.ParentProperty
                ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
                : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        //set rectangle 3 base on ChildClass Property
        sourceObject.Rectangle3.Fill =
            sourceObject.ParentClass.ChildClass.ChildProperty
                ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
                : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    }
}
```

ParentClass.cs

```
public class ParentClass :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ChildClass _childClass;
    private bool _directProperty;
    private bool _parentProperty;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ChildClass ChildClass
    {
        get { return _childClass; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _childClass)) return;
            _childClass = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool DirectProperty
    {
        get { return _directProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_directProperty)) return;
            _directProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool ParentProperty
    {
        get { return _parentProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_parentProperty)) return;
            _parentProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ChildClass.cs

```
public class ChildClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _childProperty;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool ChildProperty
    {
        get { return _childProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_childProperty)) return;
            _childProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**** Working Modified ParentClass

```
public class ParentClass :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ChildClass _childClass;
    private bool _directProperty;
    private bool _parentProperty;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public ParentClass()
    {
        PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    public ChildClass ChildClass
    {
        get { return _childClass; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _childClass)) return;
            _childClass = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            _childClass.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
            DirectProperty = !DirectProperty;
        }
    }
    public bool DirectProperty
    {
        get { return _directProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_directProperty)) return;
            _directProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool ParentProperty
    {
        get { return _parentProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_parentProperty)) return;
            _parentProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            DirectProperty = ! DirectProperty;
        }
    }
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName == "DirectProperty") return;
        // Properties that are bound to the UI you want to update
        DirectProperty = ! DirectProperty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do on your classes is to subscribe to property changed event. `INotifyPropertyChanged` gives you the ability to subscribe for `PropertyChanges`

```
    public ParentClass()
    {       
     this.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        // Properties that are bound to the UI you want to update
        OnPropertyChanged("PROPERTYNAME");
    }
```

Now that'll trigger for any property changed and gets repeated if you just update everything on each property name that was changed. You can customize how it behaves but the idea is there. You can also access properties in `PropertyChangedEventArgs` to what properties are being changed.

Comment: I had to add a check to prevent an endless loop, and calling OnPropertyChanged did not work, however changing the value of the bounded properties did.  (Dependency Property vs INotify?)  So I have a working solution.  

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are interested in the changing values of your view model (DataContext), you can bind multiple properties of your view model to a single property of your user control using a multi-value converter. If any of the properties in the binding changes, the converter will be called and you can use the converter to set a single value on your user control or do nothing. You can learn how to create or use a multi-value converter [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Sample xaml below:

```
    <UserControl1 >
        <UserControl1.DirectProperty>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverterName}">
                <Binding Path="ChildClass"/>
                <Binding Path="DirectProperty"/>
                <Binding Path="ParentProperty"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </UserControl1.DirectProperty>
    </UserControl1>
```

Sample converter below:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //return some value
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //return some value
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible, a MultiBinding is the way to go. In some cases it's less practical or inconvenient, so another option is to expose the aggregate of your other properties via a single property directly from your viewmodel.

Comment: Yes. I couldn't agree more.